# Dynamic array inside of Class template

Tags: c++11

i have want to make template class Vector , parameters should be Type and length of an dynamic array thats in it.

```
template < class Type, int length >
class Vektor
{
public:
int Count;
int CurrentPos;
Type* Beginning = new Type[count];
int LastAtUse=0;
Vektor()
{
    Count = length;
}
void PushBack(Type A)
{
    Beginning[LastAtUse]=A;
    LastAtUse++;
}
void insert(Type A, int position)
{
    Beginning[position] = A;
}
};
```

I tried to test it in main and am getting an error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from      'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type (__cdecl *)(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' to 'unsigned int'
```

Can you help me find what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
Type* Beginning = new Type[count];
                           ^
```

you have `Count`, not `count`

also, `Count` is not yet set when your `new` executes, you should move it to constructor here:

```
Vektor()
{
    Count = length;
    Beginning = new Type[Count];    
}
```

Comment: Ah yes i moved it in desperation it fixes itself ,originally had it in constructor.
Thanks a lot :) (I'm stupid xd)